# Linq GroupBy deep compare

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to groupBy in order to display some items at a print report.

```
model.OrderItems = model.OrderItems
    .GroupBy(p => p.Product.Id, (key, values) =>
    {
        values.FirstOrDefault().Quantity = values.Count();
        return values.FirstOrDefault();
    }).ToList();
```

This works fine. However each product has some preferences that I want to compare.

So i want to groupBy only if `products.Preferences` that is an `Enumerable<Preference>` are equal. Preferences implements equals()

Comment: Equal == SequenceEqual or Equal == same elements, different order still ok?

Comment: What does that mean that the preferences are 'equal'? Do they point to the same reference or do they hold the same items? And how should the items in those lists be compared? What kinds of types are in that list?

Comment: @xanatos Are you sure it is SequenceEqual ? Order doesnt matter.

Comment: @Parhs I'm asking it to you. Collection equality/equivalence isn't something "fixed", written in a big book under dictation from a higher power... For example if Preferences is an HashSet, the ordering is absolutely random, so two HashSet are equal and equivalent if they have the same items.

Comment: @Parhs Wait... `Preferences` implements `Equal`? Not `Preference` (single), `Preferences` the collection of `Preference`? (from your question: `Preferences implements equals()`)

Comment: Each Preference is a a POCO .Order is random .By equal i mean to have same Id property and same Quantity property

Comment: Preference implements Equals .

Comment: If the order doesn't matter you can probably use the `Intersect` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) method

Answer (score 0):

In the Equals implementation of Product, check for equal Preferences with this method:

```
public static bool ItemsEquals<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source1, IEnumerable<T> source2)
{
    var counter = new Dictionary<T, int>();
    foreach (T item in source1)
    {
        if (counter.ContainsKey(item))
        {
            counter[item]++;
        }
        else
        {
            counter.Add(item, 1);
        }
    }
    foreach (T item in source2)
    {
        if (counter.ContainsKey(item))
        {
            counter[item]--;
            if (counter[item] < 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return counter.Values.All(c => c == 0);
}
```